# How to use a service id in the keyUri used by a resources server to get the JWT verifier key?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I have an OAuth resource server secured with Spring cloud security.

The OAuth tokens that are used are JWT tokens, so the resource server needs a verifier key to be able to check the signature of the tokens.

In order to simplify configuration I would like the resource server to get the verifier key from the authorization provider (also a spring boot service, with an `@EnableAuthorizationServer`).

This works fine if I give the direct url of the authorization provider (using spring.oauth2.resource.jwt.keyUri), for example http://ip_of_authorization_provider/oauth/token_key.

The problem is when I want to give a service-id instead of an IP or DNS in that value, eg. http://authorization-provider/oauth/token_key.

It seems to me the problem is in JwtTokenServicesConfiguration, on line 225 of [this file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/20091b75c9a2e855a0325abc5df890805865d4e2/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/resource/ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration.java), specifically :

```
private RestTemplate keyUriRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

If the keyUriRestTemplate was Autowired I could provide my own load balanced rest template, or if there was a @ConditionalOnMissingBean(JwtAccessTokenConverter.class) on the jwtAccessTokenConverter method below I could also provide my own load balanced logic.

Is there a way to do what I want without the ugly hack of recreating the whole ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration class in my app just to put only this small modification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpler and cleaner solution :

Just ditch the autoconfiguration made by spring-cloud-security and provide your own implementation of tokenServices that provide a JwtAccessTokenConverter whose key you have provided with a LoadBalanced RestTemplate. Chances are you'll eventually want to provide other specifics in your configuration anyways ...